# Why can not set underline while using TextPaint?

Tags: java, android

When I want to add a underline, I only find a method `setUnderline(boolean param)`. But I want to change the underline's color.  So I viewed the `TextPaint`'s code. It extends `Paint`. It has the public variable `underlineColor`. But why can't I call it in my code? It seems that I can only call the `Paint`'s methods while can not call `TextPaint`'s methods and variables.